# Why shell_exec executing more than 1 process?

Tags: linux, shell, php, shell-exec

I dont understand why there is more than 1 process when I run `run.php` once from a browser

In the PHP code, I have the following:

**run.php**

```
<?php
shell_exec("php theprocess.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
?>
```

**theprocess.php**

```
<?php
$z = 1;
while ($z <= 20) {
    echo $z . "\n";
    $z++;
    sleep(3);
}
?>
```

I execute run.php from the browser (eg: http://localhost/run.php)

**Then I typed: ps aux | grep php**

```
username@ [~]# ps aux | grep php
username 27272  0.0  1.5  89504 64468 ?        R    17:33   0:00 php theprocess.php
username 27274  0.0  1.2  89504 49872 ?        R    17:33   0:00 php theprocess.php
username 27276  0.0  0.6  89504 28676 ?        R    17:33   0:00 php theprocess.php
username 27278  0.0  0.0  22280  3704 ?        R    17:33   0:00 php theprocess.php
username 27280  0.0  0.0   1940   508 ?        S+   17:33   0:00 grep php
```

I dont understand why is it showing more than 1 theprocess.php process?

Also why it still running at the background? it should terminate `theprocess.php` finish the task. How can that be done?

Comment: You've put `theprocess.php` into the background with that final `&`. If it's sitting there waiting for input, it'll wait forever.

Comment: Ahh ok, now I undestood, maybe in the end of script I could include 'kill -9 PID' ... but i dont understand why showing more than 1 process when I have executed once.

Comment: How many times did you refresh the page while testing? Each time would fire up a new theprocess...

Comment: Marc B, I did not refresh the page while testing.

Comment: strange, when I typed 'php run.php' in shell - it show one process running in the backround... but running from the browser is executing multiple php run.php hmmmm

Comment: Could you try it on your box? if you having same issue?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem!

When running script from a webpage, it does not treat as PHP cli.

Replace

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/php theprocess.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

To

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/php-cli theprocess.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

I no longer have multiple procress running in the background.