# Cannot Execute PHP Shell Script from Web Page

Tags: php, shell, philips-hue

I have [this](https://github.com/danray0424/phpHue/blob/master/huecli.php) file on my server to control my Philips Hue lights.

From the shell I run `php huecli.php -i IP -k KEY ...` it will output the proper result but when I run the following as a PHP Script, it fails (times out)

```
$output = shell_exec('php huecli.php ...');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

When I stop the script from running, I see there are a lot of outputs that look like:

> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
>
> Content-type: text/html

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to php. I.e. in the execution statement use `/usr/bin/php` or wherever you have installed it?

Comment: Yes I have tried using the full path

Comment: What does the server error log say?

Comment: "it fails" means what exactly?

Comment: Times out. I figured out issue was because i was not using `php-cli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Apparently this was the same reason as [This User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614017/why-shell-exec-executing-more-than-1-process). When I would call my file, it would apparently create thousands of processes, which is why it would timeout.

Calling `php-cli huecli.php` solves my issue.